# How to prevent browsers downloading Google AdSense ADS on Mobile with responsive site?

Tags: css, browser, adsense

With media query, I set the Div to `display:none` which contains AdSense code. However, I wanted to show another AdSense Ad which is in another DiV with `display:block`.

**Need your help in understanding the below:**
Does `display:none` will prevent sending the Ad request to Google or prevent it from downloading the AD from Google?
My challenge, the last I wanted to show will be fourth AdSense Ad and I cannot show 4 ads as per AdSense policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:none` on parent `div` does not prevent ad request from that ad unit:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1" ... ></ins>
</div>
```

That is a violation of [AdSense policy about hiding ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en): "*Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g., `display:none`), unless you're implementing a responsive ad unit.*"

To prevent ad request, we need to apply `display:none` on AdSense `ins` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display: inline-block; width: 320px; height: 50px; }
@media (max-width: 400px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
@media (min-width: 500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media (min-width: 800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
  data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

That is "[Hiding an ad unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#hide)" advanced feature. For the viewport less than 401px, above example will inject `<!--No ad requested because of display:none on the adsbygoogle tag-->` comment inside `ins` tag (instead of the advertisement).

I think my ["How to 'move' AdSense ads" JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/galeksic/r18v4v8m/) is probably what you want - "*I wanted to show another AdSense Ad which is in another DiV with `display:block`*". (Move vertical border to see ads "moving".)